# Regex to determine if string contains at least 2 numbers

Tags: android, regex

I'm try to write a username field validator and one of the reqs is that the field must contain at least 2 numbers (more is ok, just no less). I thought I could do something like this, and the regex splits on the first number, but never on the second.

```
    String[] arr = string.split("[0-9][0-9]");
    return arr.length > 2;
```

Use cases:
Bob11
Bo1b1
11Bob
1Bob1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- .* matches everything (from 0 to n times)
- [0-9] is number from 0-9

```js
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9].*[0-9]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
   return true;
}
```

And you can check regex in https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: This doesn't allow anything after the last digit.

Comment: **least 2 numbers** you know?

Comment: This got the job done. Thank you. It also give me enough of a bread crumb to figure out the rest of the req for the username pattern match. Thank you!

Comment: The full req is 2 numbers at least 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase done in three steps so each will give a separate error message. I used your response to also construct: uppercase = (".*[A-Z].*") and lowercase = (".*[a-z].*"). Thank you again.

Answer (score 7):

Below is my version, that has an extremely fast execution, can be easily updated to different criteria, and has a better readability (at least to me):

*Regex*
`(\D*\d){2,}`

*Example*

```
Bob11   - Match
Bo1b1   - Match
11Bob   - Match
1Bob1   - Match
11235   - Match

Bobb    - Does NOT Match
Bob1    - Does NOT Match
Bo1b    - Does NOT Match
1Bob    - Does NOT Match
```

*Explanation*
`\D` - non digit.
`*` - (quantifier) zero or more times.
`\d` - one digit.
`(\D*\d)` - encapsulate the combination above as a group.
`{2,}` - (quantifier) ensures that the group occurs at least 2 times, being able to occur more times.

`(\D*\d){2,}` - So, `\D*` non digit zero or infinite times, followed by a `\d` digit, this combination repeated `{2,}` two or infinite times.

*Updating to different criteria*
The `^` (start string anchor) and `$` (end string anchor) can be included to ensure restriction, in case the criteria changes to be exact 2 or any other number.
This is an example that ensures no more, no less that 5 numbers anywhere in a string: `^(\D*\d){5}\D*$`. *The last \D* is necessary to allow the string to end with a non digit, validating the regex if the criteria of five digits be satisfied.*

Answer (score 0):

`[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d.*` should be one way to go (there are several..)

- [^\d]* Matches any character which is not a digit (zero to infinite times)
- \d matches a single digit (once)
- .* matches everything (zero to infinite times)

I use `[^\d]*` because `.*` is greedy and thus *might* match too much (depending on the language). Greedy behavior can be disabled by appending `?`: `.*?`

You can test it at https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all non numeric characters  using regex and count the length

Answer (score -1):

You do not need RegEx for this. I'm not sure what language you're using, but it is safe to assume that a String in your language is essentially a Char array. If that is the case, then get the count of digit characters in the Char array and compare if it is greater than 1.

For example, here is a C# example:

```
String username = Console.ReadLine();
if (username.Count(c => Char.IsDigit(c)) > 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("The String contains 2 or more digits.");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("The String did not contain 2 or more digits.");  
}
```

This would likely yield faster results too.

Answer (score -2):

Use `string.match(‘.*\d.*\d.*’);`
It will look for one digit two times in a string.

Comment: This most propably matches everything because .* is greedy

Comment: @Ch4t4r you can try this regexp in the site you mentioned in your answer and check that it works as expected. Greediness flag is useful when several matches are available to help regexp choose one. In this case it just has to find 2 digits. However it has to find 2 at least to return a match.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote your answer. In some cases .* might not yield the wanted behavior because it's greedy - I didn't test this case though.